# Addition and deletion of sub list from main list

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists such as Main List of type `<T>` and Sub List of same type
Now there are two conditions where

- in one condition I want to remove the entire Sub List items from Main List and
- in another condition just need to add all sub list items inside the Main list.

So far I have achieved this using the foreach loop, but now I just want to do it using LINQ concept.

Is there any way?

Comment: Why do you want to do it with LINQ? Can you provide your current code?

Comment: In short, I just want to achieve Intersect and union operation.

Comment: Can you provide your current code? Forgive me, but if `.Intersect(...)` and `.Union(...)` aren't sufficient for you, you should show your current code so we can see what you're doing currently.

Comment: So, this main list, does it contains list or just object?

Comment: @Smits Well there are an `Intersect` and a `Union` method in LINQ. Where are you stuck?

Comment: Both lists contains multiple objects of type <T>.

Comment: @Smits, could you be clear in your question because intersect is not 'remove the Sub List from Main List'

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for posting your ideas, got the exact answer from @Sweeper idea, I just resolve this by using int type Lists, Here I am posting my answer,

```
       `List<int> MainList = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        List<int> SubList = new List<int>() { 4,5};

        MainList=MainList.Except(SubList).ToList();

        MainList = MainList.Union(SubList).ToList();`
```

Comment: Please be aware that `Except` is not `Intersect` for the reasons I provided in comments to Damitha's answer.

Comment: But Except does the same what exactly I want.

Comment: Smits, please post your working code in future if you are asking about alternatives, as between your question and your comment you made the situation confusing for everyone. If you had posted your code, it would have been clear to everyone precisely what you wanted to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

As per my understanding of your question,

```
            List<Object> x = new List<Object>();
            List<Object> y = new List<Object>();

            if (somecondition)
            {
                x = x.Except(y).ToList();
            }
            else if (anotherCondition)
            {
                x = x.Concat(y).ToList();
            }
```

Comment: OP wants intersect and union. Intersect is not the same as Except and Union is not the same as Concat.

Comment: Consider the sets: X: `1,2,3` and Y: `2,3`. Intersect will return `2`. Except will return `1`. Concat will return `1,2,3,2,3`. Union will return `1,2,3`.

Comment: @john, from the question alone that was hard to tell.; cause op state 'remove the Sub List from Main List' thats not common row in both list.

Comment: @DragandDrop But the purpose of comments it to clarify the question, and clearly in the comments OP said "In short, I just want to achieve Intersect and union operation." Either OP has mixed up his terminology, or these answers are wrong.

Comment: yes, I know that but OP wants to add and remove... how can you achieve deletion using intersect? Intersect returns common elements in both lists while Union Concat and handle duplicates?

Comment: @DamithaShyamantha Which is precisely why I was trying to get OP to post his code so that we could clarify what he wanted. In one place he said he wanted to remove elements that were present in a sublist, elsewhere he said he wanted to do intersection. Concat does not handle duplicates.

Comment: Well my point is op ask for blue then comments that he really wants red. And then op answer that he needed violet. We were all wrong. Op had no idea.

Comment: And if he'd posted his existing code with his question, it would have been clear to everyone.

Comment: @john what I meant by "while Union Concat and handle duplicates" that union concat two lists and handle duplicate elements...